# Is it possible to control vibration intensity with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, vibration

I'm developing an Android app with React Native.

I want to control **vibration intensity** of Android phone but I cannot find the way in the [API doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration).

Is there any way to control **vibration intensity** with React Native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to control the intensity. I think vibration is either on or off. However, you should be able to mock different intensities by using different vibration patterns.
For example, a light intensity vibration could look like:

```
Vibration.vibrate([15,1], true);
```

And a heavy vibration pattern could look like:

```
Vibration.vibrate([10,5], true);
```

Where the first item in the array is the separation duration, the second item in the array is the vibration duration, and the `true` value tells the method to repeat.